# Is this SSO implementation secure?

Tags: security, cryptography, hash, single-sign-on

A client has asked us to devise a simple Single sign-on solution for their vendors. In this situation, the client has many vendors with the capabilities to implement a simple solution which allows the vendors' users to sign in to our client's site. I came up with this:

**Shared data**

The following data will be shared between us and a given vendor.

- user_id - *Provided by vendor*
- vendor_id - *Provided by us*
- vendor_secret - *Provided by us. "Random" SHA512 hash*

**Shared hashing function**

Our specification will define the following practice for producing a key that is suitable for transmission via URL parameters:

```
// Pseudo-code. Assume sha512() is a function in their native language that accepts a string and returns a SHA-512 hash
vendor_id = 341;
vendor_secret = "areallylonghash...";
user_id = "12345abcdef;&";
hash = sha512(vendor_id + ":" + vendor_secret + ":" + user_id);
```

**SSO Process**

1. User clicks "log in" on a vendor's site and a GET request is issued to the vendor's SSO entry point.
2. Vendor recieves request on entry point (Say www.avendor.com/sign_in).
3. Vendor uses hashing function above to generate hash for user.
4. Vendor redirects to our client's endpoint with the parameters `vendor_id`, `user_id`, and `hash`.
5. We receive a request at our endpoint. We look up the vendor_secret from the vendor_id passed and attempt to recreate the `hash` that was sent to us.
6. If the generated hash matches, create a session on the client's site.

**Potential problems**

If we're using a GET request for the redirection step 4 is it possible that the generated hash could end up in a user's browser history? Not very secure if someone can just click on a link in the history. Could we use HTTP headers to transmit the hash when redirecting?

If you've gotten this far, thank you. All feedback is welcome! We're like to make sure we're deploying a secure solution.

Comment: Can you use one of the many OpenId libraries http://openid.net/developers/libraries/ for your solution?

Comment: Unfortunately the vendor we've spoken with is not open to adopting an open SSO standard... I know that sounds ridiculous, but they're not willing to invest the time in implementing something like OpenID or OAuth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer: no, it is not secure.

In step 4, the user agent gains access to `vendor_id`, `user_id`, and `hash`. Now the client can append any string they want to the `user_id` and modify the `hash` to match. I'm not sure I fully understand your proposal, but it seems like this might enable one user to log in as another user whose username is a prefix of their own.

You need to use a [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) instead of a plain hash.

[Stay away from implementing your own crypto!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ySQl0NhW1J0)

Comment: no, they can't modify the params to match. my understanding is the vendor secret is stored on the vendor and the application but never transmitted, only used as part of the signature generation. this is exactly how rails handles cookie session data which afaik is secure.

Comment: Ehren is correct. Also note that `vendor_id` and `user_id` are being matched against the database on our end, so message integrity is ensured based on a match.

Comment: @EhrenMurdick given `SHA512(341:unknown_string:Celada)` I can give you `SHA512(341:unknown_string:Celada2)`. I don't need to know what `unknown_string` is equal to in order to do that. This is what hash [length extension attacks](http://rdist.root.org/2009/10/29/stop-using-unsafe-keyed-hashes-use-hmac/) are all about.

Comment: @bloudermilk yes, the `user_id` would be validated against the database, so you could only try to impersonate a user that actually exists. Yes if I want to impersonate `bloudermilk` all I have to do is create a new account called `bloudermil` and then I can add a `k`.

Comment: @Celada Interesting... I was not aware of hash length extension attacks... Makes sense given my (limited) knowledge of how sha works. However doesn't this attack require knowledge of how the signature is generated? Also, can you seal it up by changing it to SHA512(user_id:vendor_id:vendor_secret) ?

Comment: <del>Also, can you seal it up by changing it to SHA512(user_id:vendor_id:vendor_secret) ?</del><ins>actually reading the linked article now</ins>

Comment: As you probably already read in the article, changing the order of the data that goes into the hash does close the length extension attack but there are still other attacks (beyond my understanding) so just be safe and use a HMAC instead of a raw hash like the experts (not me!) recommend.

Answer (score 2):

3(b) Vendor issues API request to your app with a generated token

3(c) Your app saves token with user_id

4() Vendor redirects with params user_id, vendor_id, token, hash

If token matches one from api, log user in, delete token

Then the redirect url is a one-time use

OR

Don't do an extra API request. Use time based rotating RSA key. Then the redirect URL only works for 5 seconds or whatever.

Comment: The token idea is a good one, though I'd prefer that we generate the token and the vendor issues a `GET` requests to us to get the latest token for a user. Doesn't this also render the `hash` parameter unnecessary?